# Why I shouldn't use toJS() in React Redux? (mapStateToProps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I've just read it on Redux's docs, that I shouldn't really use Immutable with Redux.
I just can't my head around this thing. Why I shouldn't use toJS() in the mapStateToProps?
I mean React is using Deep Compare, AND I didn't had any re-render problem with it yet. (I just logging on render to see if is there any leak.)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186890/correct-way-to-use-immutablejs-tojs-and-fromjs-with-redux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why I shouldn't use toJS() in the mapStateToProps

You shouldn't use `toJS()` in `mapStateToProps` because `toJS()` returns a new object reference and even though `connect` is pure(i.e. it does shallow comparison), it may so happen that its returns a **false negative** when the object is nested and in this case your component will re-render i.e the `render` function will be called and react will have to run the diffing algorithm which will have a performance impact as the size of your App goes.

Comment: Hmm but why would it re-render when React will do the deep compare, so if the value itself is the same it's won't re-render?

Comment: I am sure I missing something. :/
I mean ofc, the ref will change, but the value itself won't, but it's obvious, so I am sure that I missing something important, and can't see the full picture. (if you could give me an example, that would be a huge help :D)

Comment: Its not that just re-render adds to performance, say object has two level of nesting, and when shallow comparing in PureComponent, the object references are compared and hence it will return false. now after that the component render() function is called and it is here that react compares the previous and current DOM and decides where to render or not. Now this computation is heavy and the more number of times it needs to do this computation, the more is the performance penalty

Comment: I see, that totally makes sense. I will try to avoid using ImmutableJS with Redux from now on. Thanks mate! :)

Comment: @IstvanOrban, No you are getting it wrong, you should avoid using toJS method in mapStateToProps, you should instead prefer using ImmutableJS, just because in order to know if the value changed, you just need to check the reference and hence the comparison is much faster.