# Correct way to use immutablejs (toJS and fromJS) with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I wonder if this is a correct way to use `immutable.js` with redux and `reselect` (also `redux-saga`). Specifically I wonder about `toJS()` and from `fromJS()` and where to use them.
My idea is that:

1. I use `toJS()` when sending data to a saga.
2. I **do not use** `fromJS()` in reducer because I think that it is done anyway by the fact that I use `fromJS()` for initialState.  Or am I wrong about that?
3. I use `toJS()` in selector from `reselect` so I can use js data in react component.

Example:

1) In my react component I do:

```
// mapDispatchToProps
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
         loginRequest: values => dispatch(loginRequest(values)),
      };
   }

// Sending values.toJS() to my redux-saga. 
   submit = values => {
      this.props.loginRequest(values.toJS());
   };
```

2) In reducer I do (**should** one use `fromJS()` here or not? According to redux docs you should):

```
const { fromJS } = require('immutable');
const state = fromJS({
  pages: {
    usersPage: {
      loading: false,
      isFetched: false,
      list: [],
    }
  }
});
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'USERS_LOADED':
      return state
        .setIn(['usersPage', 'list'], action.payload) // fromJS() here or not?
        .setIn(['usersPage', 'isFetched'], true)
        .setIn(['usersPage', 'loading'], false)
        ;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

3) In my selector I do `toJS()` again:

```
const selectUser = state => state.get('user', initialState);
const makeSelectList= () =>
   createSelector(selectUser, userState => userState.getIn(['usersPage', 
'list']).toJS());

// Which I then use in my react component:
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
   list: makeSelectList(),
});
```

So basically I wonder if that is a correct flow of convertion between js and immutable. Or can it be optimized in some way (less convertion steps)? Maybe the above is a non-optimal way of logic?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The saga--being redux middleware--can handle Immutable types directly, no need to use an expensive `toJS` call here
2. Any point you're converting (e.g. `set`, `setIn`, `update`, etc) a plain JS non-simple type into the Immutable redux state tree, use `fromJS` to ensure a fully Immutable type [Make entire state tree immutable](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingimmutablejs#make-your-entire-redux-state-tree-an-immutable-js-object)
3. IMHO, selectors (e.g. `reselect`)--by providing memoization after the initial retrieval--can be the most ideal place to utilize the expensive `toJS` calls, as in your example #3. I guess it really depends upon how much one dislikes using Immutable retrieval methods in their "container/smart" components, and/or creating a whole bunch of selectors to retrieve simple JS types from the redux state tree [Use Immutable everywhere](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingimmutablejs#use-immutable-js-everywhere-except-your-dumb-components)

To me there's the question of where to actually use the `fromJS` call, e.g. action creators, in the "container/smart" components dispatch or, in the reducer, e.g. `react-boilerplate` uses the `fromJS` call in the reducer.

Comment: Thanks, but in 1) I get error if not using toJS() in example.

Comment: @user1665355 Is `values` an Immutable type or has it been `fromJS`'d in that instance?

Comment: `values` are from redux-form, and yes they are immutable `Map`

Comment: Clarification, I use `toJS()` in 1) because of I pass those values to `fetch` which needs plain js values.

Comment: And you are correct that `react-boilerplate` uses `fromJS` in reducer, as well as they use `toJS` in selector :)

Comment: Btw, great answer and links for a totally new SO person. Big thanks :)

Comment: One question just, so I `don't` actually need to convert to js values with `toJS()` when using immutable from state in my components? Meaning I should i.e. use `.get(), .set()` etc in components?

Comment: @user1665355 correct, at least regarding "smart/container" components, i.e. components that map selector values to props. You'd pass any plain JS types to any child "dumb" components the "smart/container" components leverage. A reason why the redux docs point to this method is that `shouldComponentUpdate` becomes a trivial "deep" comparison on your Immutable props (retrieved from the redux state tree via selectors)